# Magento 2 admin URL not working - Need SSH commands

Tags: magento-2.1

I cannot access Magento 2 admin after making URL settings change in the admin panel.  I set the Base Link URL setting to my domain name, but left the Base URL setting in xxx.xx.xxx.xx format.  Now the admin URL is not working, either using the domain or the xxx.xx.xxx.xx format.  Can someone provide me with the step by step instructions for getting this resolved using SSH?  Currently on Magento 2.1.7

Answer (score 0):

Try changing admin url using SSH as follows.

```
php bin/magento setup:config:set --backend-frontname="admin_path"
```